# Order of the fundamental Group of a root system and the determinant of the Cartan Matrix

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional simple Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Let for some fixed cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$, $\Phi$ be the root system of $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $\Delta=\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{\ell}\}$ be a simple system for $\Phi$. Let $P=\{\lambda\in\mathfrak{h}^*\mid (\lambda,\alpha^\vee)\in\mathbb{Z}\quad \forall \alpha\in\Delta\}$ be the weight lattice and $Q=Span_{\mathbb{Z}}\Delta$ be the root lattice. Then $Q\subseteq P$. If $w_1,w_2,\dots,w_{\ell}$ are the fundamental dominant weights, then $P$ is a lattice with basis $w_1,w_2,\dots,w_{\ell}$. Let $A$ be the Cartan matrix of $\Phi$.

**My Question is**: How to prove that the order of the group $P/Q$ is same as $det(A)$?

**My progress so far :**

I could express $\alpha_i$'s in terms of $w_i$s and coefficient are Cartan integers. By inverting the system I showed that $det(A)w_i\in Q$ for all $i$. But don't know how to prove that the order is $det(A)$.

For classical cases we have a very explicit description of $w_i$ s in terms of $\alpha_i$ s, there it's not hard to see that order is indeed $det(A)$. But I'm trying to find a case free solution.

For general case I tried to use the stacked basis theorem for finitely generated free abelian groups but could not come up with and ans.

Any suggestion is welcomed and appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It follows from Smith normal form: since the Cartan matrix expresses the simple roots in the basis of fundamental weights, $\alpha_j = \sum_i A_{ij} \varpi_i$, by SNF there exist matrices $X, Y \in \operatorname{GL}_\ell(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $XAY = D$ for a diagonal matrix $D$. So there exist alternative bases $p_i$ of $P$ and $q_i$ of $Q$ such that $p_i = d_i q_i$, and so $P/Q \cong \mathbb{Z}_{d_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{d_\ell}$. Now use that $\det(D)$ is the product of the $d_i$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know much about SNF. Taking that as granted remaining is crystal clear. A quick query: What would be the good reference for SNF?

Comment: It comes up in the classification of finitely generated abelian groups, or the classification of finitely generated modules over a PID. Many abstract algebra textbooks and course notes will have a section on one or both of these things.

Comment: Thank you very much.